# Does a const instantiation of a custom class make *everything* in the class constant too?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, constants, const-iterator

1. How do most compilers actually deal with const? What does it mean technically? (not practically)

When I say *everything* I mean, suppose I have a custom class with a container as a member field, and then a function that passes by reference values and appends them into that member field.

2. If I have a const instantiation of this class, will constantness filter down?
3. If I have a const STL iterator of a non const container (of my sharedPointers to instantiations of my custom class), what exactly is const about it? Will I be able to alter the contents of the container using the aforementioned function? Will the pointed to data be mutable but nothing else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Off topic for this site.
2. **If I have a const instantiation of this class, will constantness filter down?**  Yes.
3. **If I have a const STL iterator of a non const container.** If `const iterator` then you cannot increment or decrement the iterator, but you can use it to modify its referent.  If `const_iterator` then you can increment or decrement it, but you cannot use it to modify its referent.  In either case, other non-const iterators to the container may also exist, so the container may be modified by them.

Comment: 1. hmmm ok. I thought since there was a tag "compiler-construction" that defined its use as: "The tag [compiler-construction] should be applied to questions concerning the programming of compilers or for questions about the detailed inner workings of compilers.
3. Really? even with pointers? I have a const_iterator with which I say `QMap<QPoint, RandoTemplateSharedPtrToCustomClass >::const_iterator iter = m_bla.myObjects.begin();`

`iter.value()->addPos(QPoint(i, j));`

Comment: 3. I have a const_iterator that is the only thing modifying m_bla.myObjects and I print everything before and after. I can witness the change. Is it a QT specific thing?

Comment: 3. right. of course. you can't modify it's referent, and I have a memory address that doesn't get modified. silly me. Thank you! So, does that mean that member arrays can be modified? i suppose that brings me to the filter down part of the question. It can't filter down through pointed-to data but what about members of members?, how does the filtering down work and how are custom object members stored memory wise?

Comment: @user2309274: When you have a const instance of a class, it is as if all the members of that class are const, and you can only call const methods.  But a pointer type like `const OtherThing*` means you cannot modify the pointer to point to something else...it does not stop you from using the pointer to modify the `OtherThing`.  If you have a non-pointer member like `OtherThing` it will become `const OtherThing` and then everything inside it will be considered const too.